# How to load the any panorama images from url into android devices?

Tags: android, 360-panorama

Explanation:
            I want to load an panorama image from the url and load into fragment or any other view in android.I am new to android i don't know how to load that image from url.I tried lot of demos but they all are some restriction.In some of the demos it must be height always divide by two and width of the image is double than height. It has some restriction. fact is the image which on server it's of any size.

Description about panorama image:
                   Panorama images are image which rotate 360 degree horizontally and 180 degree vertically.

Problem I don't have initial idea to load the panorama image from the url.

Comment: i don't want to load simple image from url.I want to load the image from url and move 360 degree.

Comment: Understand my question first.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official support for showing panoramic images in android.I haven't tried it myself but you can try using some library like this one [here](https://github.com/marianmoldovan/panoramagl).